# Why my variable is undefined here in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Here is my Nodejs code

```
exports.symbol = function(req, res){
symbol = req.params.s;
    //No issues here!!!
console.log("Symbol = " + symbol);

async.parallel({
    A: function(callback, symbol){
        //symbol is undefined here???
        functionA("http://www.xyz.com?tickersymbols=" + symbol, function(result){
            callback(null, result);
        });
    },
    B: function(callback,symbol){
        //symbol is undefined here???
        functionB("http://www.xyz.com?&tickersymbols=" + symbol, function(result){
            callback(null, result);
        });
    },
    C: function(callback,symbol){
        //symbol is undefined here???
        functionC(symbol,function(result){
            callback(null, result);
        });
    }
},function(err, results){
    res.send(results);
});
```

}

The problem is variable symbol is undefined in the place indicated. How can i pass this param to the function.

Comment: This code (adding the "async = require('async');" line to the top) gives me no warnings, but of course it won't run because it's incomplete. If you gave us a complete trimmed example we could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined because your function is expecting it to be passed in.  Remove it from the function setup like this so that the `symbol` reference will be set to the one in the outer function.

```
async.parallel({
    A: function(callback){
        //symbol should be defined now
        functionA("http://www.xyz.com?tickersymbols=" + symbol, function(result){
            callback(null, result);
        });
    },
    B: function(callback){

        functionB("http://www.xyz.com?&tickersymbols=" + symbol, function(result){
            callback(null, result);
        });
    }});  //etc
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question indicating that he wants the outer "symbol" rather than the argument, but the example isn't complete enough to diagnose.

Comment: That was the problem. Made the change and it works now. Thanks